# FIRESTORE: How to iterate the table based on the condition

Tags: firebase

Here is the problem statement -> I need to get the list of users whose preference->district matches my district.

As you can see in the screenshot that there are two tables `users` and `user_preference`. I am trying to get the list of users whose `preference->district` (Here I kept the id of the user_preference documents entry in the user->preference key) matches to the `user->district` of the user which is at index 0.

Like for example, the user at index 0, the name is 'SACHIT' and the district is 'Saharanpur' and the user at index 3 has one preference whose id starts from `d61a29.....`. Let's see the same id in the user_preference and as you can see in the screenshot that this id is at index 3 in `user_preference` table and the district is Saharanpur. So ideally it should return this match and so on...

Here is what I tried but it's returning the wrong data

```
let userArray = [];
      await db
        .collection("users")
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function (userDoc) {
            if (userDoc.data().uid != uid) {
              let prefArray = userDoc.data().preferences;
              prefArray.forEach((pref) => {
                db.collection("user_preference")
                  .where("district", "==", user.district)
                  .get()
                  .then((snapshot) => {
                    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                      userArray.push(userDoc.data());
                    });
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              });
            }
          });
        });
```

[image: Screenshot1] [image: Screenshot2] [image: Screenshot3] [image: Screenshot4]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you are trying to query user's `district` matching document from `user_preferences` collection.

Here, the member `user` in your where condition is not defined earlier. so changing that to below may work!

```
.where("district", "==", userDoc.data().district)
```